# ExpandableListView dentro de TabLayout y ViewPager pero no se muestra

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Buenas!, necesito una ayudilla, tengo inicialmente un TabLayout con ViewPager y 4 fragmentos, 3 de ellos con listas personalizadas y funcionando correctamente, en la pestaña(fragmento) restante quiero añadir un ExpandableListView con su lógica implementada pero no consigo que se muestre, aqui mi fragmento:

```
public class OcioFragment extends Fragment{

ExpandableListView expandableListView;
ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
List<String> expandableListTitle;
HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ocio_expandable,null,false);

    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista_expandible);
    expandableListDetail = opcionesOcio.getData();
    expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
    expandableListAdapter = new miAdaptadorExpan(getContext(), expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

El adaptador definido en otra clase y las opciones del list a su vez en otra pero no consigo que se muestre... alguna idea?
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

soy nuevo por aquí y quizá no puse la respuesta acertada o detallada;

No mostraba el expandable porque no estaba pasando el contenido definido en mi clase opciones,que es donde tengo definido el contenido del ExpandableListView, al final no le había pasado el .put() a cada lista por eso mismo no las mostraba.

EJEMPLO expandableListDetail.put("Centros Comerciales", centroco);

Tras pasarle los argumentos a cada lista, se solucionó el problema.

Gracias